# How to create a formula that can count values across multiple columns in specified rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet where I have multiple tasks and multiple products. Each task for each product is rated red. amber or green depending on progress so far. Each task also has an owner.

I want to create another table which shows how many red, amber and green ratings are assigned to each owner. I can do this very easily with a countif function, but the additional problem is that new tasks and owners are being added to the bottom of my list by others in my dept. So the only way I can keep my table up to date is to constantly reorder the table by owner, and adjust the ranges in the countif.

Here's a link to an example I made:
[image]

I've found a few Index functions that can return multiple values and count up the values but I'm not smart enough to make them work across multiple columns.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current layout, you can use this in cell J4:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($D$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1,COUNTA($2:$2)-2)=J$3)*(OFFSET($C$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1)=$I4))
```

`COUNTA($C:$C)-1` returns the height of the data table (the `-1` is to disregard the header row). This relies on column C which contains the owners and there shouldn't be data after the last owner or contain blanks between rows in the data itself.

`COUNTA($2:$2)-2` similarly returns the breadth of the data table (and this time, I have `-2` because there are 2 columns before the dataset starts). Again, there shouldn't be missing headers in the table.

`(OFFSET($D$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1,COUNTA($2:$2)-2)` returns the range starting at D3 and with height and breadth calculated above.

`OFFSET($C$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1)` returns the range containing the owners.

`(OFFSET($D$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1,COUNTA($2:$2)-2)=J$3)` compares the data with the cell J3. In my table, I put `r` in J3 so that I could drag the formula across the table only twice without having to change anything in the formula, but you can substitute the `J$3` with `"r"`, you'll just have to adjust it for each column once. The expression will return `TRUE` for matches and `FALSE` otherwise.

`(OFFSET($C$3,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-1)=$I4)` compares the owners with the owner in cell I4. Returns `TRUE` for matches and `FALSE` otherwise.

When the above two results are multiplied together, you end up with a series of `1` and `0` which `SUMPRODUCT` adds up to give a count.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to just use the basic SUMPRODUCT with a range large enough to allow some expansion, e.g. for up to 100 rows `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$100=$I4)*($D$3:$G$100=J$3))`

Comment: @barryhoudini I was too at the start but decided I'd go with the notorious OFFSET just because of that summary table on the side. If possible, I'd advise for changing the layout the table entirely and put the products into a column. I think it's more maintainable and can be summarise with some simple COUNTIFS.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks, I've adapted your formula to my real table and it works perfectly. Really appreciate your help and the step by step breakdown made it really clear to follow. PS - I would love to change the formatting, sadly the others in my department hate change so they will freak out if I mess with their task list layout!

Comment: @JO'Brien I know the feeling! Lots of people who are at a task for years rarely rarely can cope with changes, and it's sometimes a pity, because as time goes, there are often better ways to do the same thing before which makes things less time consuming (hence less costly). Oh well.